# Eigen Matrix-Vector multiplication w/ noalias

Tags: c++, eigen

I've been going through the Eigen documentation for using [noalias](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html) to avoid unnecessary temporary allocations when doing  Matrix-Matrix products, but I was wondering if it's possible to use noalias in the following situation:

```
Eigen::VectorXf x(3);
x << 1, 2, 3;

Eigen::MatrixXf A(3, 3);
A << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;

// Is this valid? Is it valid under certain size assumptions for A and x but not others?
x.noalias() = A * x;
```

Naively, it seems like noalias might be valid in this case because you really only need to access the Vector elements once per column in the Matrix.

On the other hand, x clearly appears on both sides of the expression, and matrix multiplication involves all sorts of low level black magic that makes situations like this hard to reason about.

Comment: No by definition, this is not a correct usage of the `noalias` member.

Comment: I agree that by definition it’s not a correct usage of noalias. Maybe a better way to phrase the question would be, “If I use noalias as above, can I both avoid the temporary and get the correct answer?”

Comment: You may avoid the temporary, but you are at the mercy of the implementation and your compiler if you want the correct result. I tested your code with the trunk Eigen code and the latest GCC, the results with `noalias` are incorrect.

Comment: Alas... ha. Thanks for the help. If you posted as the answer to my question, I’d accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [testing with Clang trunk and Eigen trunk](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJICspLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiXSaQAOqBYXVaPUMTM0tffzU6OwdnIzcPTi8lFSjaBgJmYgJg41MLRWVMVUCMrIIYp1d3T0VM7NzQgoV6ivsq%2BJqkgEpFVANiZA4AcikAZntkQywAanExnXUW4kxmI3nscQAGAEFxyenMOYXsPGAtAHoAES0lDe293eYDIhnaVAB9NjxmBQhumYAWg2M1O51MIAAasUiMQABpUB7iADssl2MwxoLOWhAUJhJARMwAHhAxt15midpjiccdPMdDNOKQZl4ZmMKUj0ZiwTiQABZZgEYh4ImEnak5lkjlcjFU%2Bn0xnM1ljZm8GaWGYANmZyOZAA5mQBOaWPKmYokAOne31%2B/2OVxmVIAVMSTdSVgQBrRXWNKSirpyds9Xja/gDgWNsFjwbjoaoCYjdijKdSeRC47DCSSpb6HtSibSFUyWZKTXnudiIQKhSKxRK2eTczLHYWFoqS2zVcyNdqZrqZgaZsam6b8/aWy6iW7MR6vT6/ciA0ndvYCDMjMx7DM7UjUeWMS10Li0C9WwypJIrahQxezzND7jrKxpxiaMRt2haC0ZsHUFJNW8qAzCAgFfKwPxhuSzbJvu1L3gQR4oP0a7ym27x3g%2BIBPi%2BcyLoG1KYSeKELAqF43pIkgYQhj7aM%2BI7Um%2BH50N%2Bv7/oBwE/uBtrdFBZoYjBzYEdRSGnqhDLoWJ8GIdh9GYv6u5XMMvSsCAwzmMMpCmMMWwaagql0jIcj3v0gxHOMnAaQQqk6TxpAANYgOY5gWmM5iSNwepbNwnDIsi5jcOYuoqcM3AaVpOmkHpwwaQoIBbKQVnaUppBwLAMCIEhRjeHg7BkBQEBoFlOU1FMIjAB8QoGLQdmkFQOUEO4sUQC41kaS49hZAAnq1pCFUYWgEAA8rQrDdUlpBYBuojsD1%2BArCUABumCxeNmBEsULwjBFq7KD14EuMQXV6FgqkWQlwpGKdyU0PQTBsBwPD8IIwiiCgchyEIeAuLFsC0GsHCYJWpBLR4lXVbZqDeGkK2AoNYxAoe8xXBIhkyD5MVFCUGgQNYjSmEy1iVHECSCBEAR0HjpN%2BOTtBE9UiSFKkpStJTTIpDCzPlHTnQMy05Ss3UXPtMTXS9AoJlDFwymqepmk9VFRJ6pqgKatwMylaI25g3ZAIQLghAkHMkhjMWehFblRsmwCBmyDIlmtbZDmSJqFpbKrhreeYYyGmMWxK%2BY2rBaFpCXeY8XhbpqkxXFCUOyl6UQEgyHeC85CUIV2W5YImD4LCgg3YwLAzY9ADuh3eFd0tqWF8uqeZMwl4QCDEkrKtqxrwBa8QVU6/bSW2QgqxYB4/xCKpweh%2BHtfRYoMeJTZvQOdw3AWqrfmcIa5h6hRAXcCqwVjDX41RX3C9j8MkhHxFJ%2Bx/3vQg/4GjcEAA%3D%3D), with optimizations turned on, the case with `noalias` produces incorrect results. GCC trunk has the same behaviour.

The outputs:

```
Program returned: 0
.noalias
0
0
0
alias
14
32
50
```

---

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

auto no_alias() -> Eigen::VectorXf
{
    Eigen::VectorXf x(3);
    x << 1, 2, 3;

    Eigen::MatrixXf A(3, 3);
    A << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;

    x.noalias() = A * x;
    return x;
}

auto alias() -> Eigen::VectorXf
{
    Eigen::VectorXf x(3);
    x << 1, 2, 3;

    Eigen::MatrixXf A(3, 3);
    A << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;

    x = A * x;
    return x;
}

int main () 
{
    std::cout << ".noalias" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& no : no_alias())
    {
        std::cout << no << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "alias" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& no : alias())
    {
        std::cout << no << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: does that mean it's safe to write statements like x = Ax ?

Comment: @Hirek It is safe, it becomes unsafe when you use `noalias()` incorrectly.